# Find which python modules are being imported

Tags: python, package

What's an easy way of finding all the python modules from a particular package that are being used in an application?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`sys.modules` is a dictionary mapping module names to modules.  You can examine its keys to see imported modules.

See: http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.modules

Comment: I am not sure the details as to why but this does not actually contain **ALL** the available packages.  I was trying to identify where python was importing `multiprocessing` which was not in the list.  Using `python -v`, with the verbose flag worked.

Comment: @stvn66 it isn't meant to be a list of available packages.  It's all of the modules that have actually been imported. It's the structure that ensures when you import a module twice, you get the same module object, and avoid executing the code twice.

Comment: @NedBatchelder, I obviously read your post too quickly.  That makes sense.

Comment: @NedBatchelder Can you be more explicit because `for key in sorted(sys.modules) : print(str(key))` outputs many things. I just want the imported modules list.

Comment: @NedBatchelder modules lists far more than just the module you imported.  To demo this you can open a fresh python terminal, from sys import modules, 'math' in modules, and get true despite never having imported math

Answer (score 35):

You could use `python -v`, which will emit messages about *every* imported module:

```
$ echo 'print "hello world"' > helo.py
$ python -v helo.py
# installing zipimport hook
import zipimport # builtin
# installed zipimport hook
# /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site.pyc matches /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site.py
import site # precompiled from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site.pyc
# /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/os.pyc matches /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/os.py
import os # precompiled from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/os.pyc
import posix # builtin
# /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/posixpath.pyc matches /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/posixpath.py
import posixpath # precompiled from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/posixpath.pyc
```

...and so on, and so forth.  Of course you can later `grep` the modules of interest from among this large list!-)

Comment: Under linux you'll have to use python -v helo.py 2>stuff.txt , to allow grep, as -v seems to output to stderr.

Answer (score 2):

I think [modulefinder](http://docs.python.org/library/modulefinder.html) is what you're looking for. You can use `modulefinder.py` directly, running it as a script as is described there, or you can [import the module and then create a report](http://docs.python.org/library/modulefinder.html#example-usage-of-modulefinder) using the `modulefinder.ModuleFinder` class.

Comment: It doesn't provide as much information as @Alex Martelli's answer provides.

Answer (score 0):

A real simple method is to delete all .pyc files from the package or folder, and then run the application.  Once you've played a bit, do a directory listing and see which files have .pyc files now.  Those are modules which were imported by the application.

(Note: the  `__main__` module, whichever one you invoke as the "main" script, never gets compiled, so you should not expect to see a .pyc file for it unless something imported it from within the application.  This is often a sign of a problem if it does happen.)