# Python: Print functioncalls and namespaces

Tags: python, module

I was wondering, for debugging purposes, if it is possible to see what namespaces and modules you are operating with once you do an import and furthermore to see where a function was called.

If I have a function f(x) and a rather complicated structure in my code, is there a way to see where f(x) is being called without adding prints all over the place?

Something like      f.print_occurance()

```
"f was called in function integrate"
"f was called in function linspace"
"f was called in function enumerate"
```

Something similar to do this.

As for the first question, suppose I import a module "import somemodule"
Now if that module imports other modules, can I see what namespaces and modules have been imported/used without looking up somemodule.py (or its header file if it exists like in c/cpp).

Sorry if this is a newbie question, just seems like basic tricks I should know for error handling and debugging but googling returned nothing useful.

Comment: If there's an uncaught exception within Python, then you'll get the exception with a "traceback" which will provide all that information for you... So, I think this is a bit of a non-question... [Try typing `10 / 0` inside your interpreter for instance]

Comment: Check out the `inspect` module

Comment: In addition to what Jon says: http://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html

Comment: For modules, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997449/find-which-python-modules-are-being-imported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely look at the [traceback](http://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html) and [inspect](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) modules.

For a simple way to do this:

```
traceback.print_stack(limit=2)
```

This will be ugly, but tell you which function is being called and what called it. You can look at the modules for how to use them to fit your needs.

You can look at the imported modules with [sys.modules](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.modules)

Answer (score 2):

You could possibly write your own f.print_occurence() attribute. Create a varible that flags 'true' when the function starts then the f.print_occurence() will recognize the flag and print accordingly.